# Creating a real android phone image which can be load by Android SDK

Tags: android

Is there a way to create a real android phone image which can be load by Android SDK. Which mean, the Android SDK will load my actual phone image instead of the SDK image.

"Not to running on the phone but running the image in the emulator"

There are similar question out there, but I cannot find the answer that solve this problem, therefore I asked here again. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand your question, why do you want to do this? Aesthetics.. For all practical reasons (like testing) you only have to change the screen resolution and android api targets of your emulator to simulate any phone model.

Comment: If you want to change the actual look and feel you need to change the android emulator skin. Google for android emulator skin *phone name*.Download the skin and You can change your skin in android emulator skin dropdown.(while creating a new Virtual device)

Comment: It is for some research and testing. We have a Android phone which is shared by 3 of us and we are all researching about the phone. Then I was curious about if we can work on that phone image instead of the sdk image.

Comment: Well, if your phone is a popular model, then you might be able to find a skin. For example, the following link have skins for some popular android phones. http://www.android.encke.net. (otherwise you may have to create your own skin).